# Vertical alignment of flexboxes via css

Tags: html, css

I have a weird use case where I need to have a first div (link) floating left over the whole height of the parent (orw). This height will change dynamically. The other siblings (orders) take the rest of horizontal space. The problem is they don't jump into the next row, I would need to have only one orders div per row.

```
<div class="orw">
<span class="link">ss</span>
<div class="orders">sdddds<div class="status">sss</div></div>
<div class="orders">sdddds<div class="status">sss</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.orw {display: flex; width: 100%; height: 200px;  }
.link {display: flex; position: relative; float: left; background: #ccc; width: 100px; height: 100%; position: relative;align-items: center; justify-content: center;}
.orders {display: flex; position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; background: #f92; height: 100%; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}
.status {background: #ccc; display: flex; position: relative; width: 100px; float: right; height: 100%; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/fsL2cbq3/3/

Comment: Float will not work in a flex container

Comment: Sorry, it's not clean, I tried different approaches. Grids, table-cells, but I cannot get it working. Unfortunately I cannot change the div structure due to JS prepends/appends.

Comment: @jq1080 you mean that you cannot change the html structure? Because the task could easily be done if simply wrap two orders in another `div`.

Comment: [This article may assist you](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this: A mix of old style positioning layout for the split between the link area and the orders area, and flexbox for the internals of each.

```css
.orw { position:relative; padding-left:100px;}
.orw * { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}
.link { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; width:100px;}
.orders { background: #f92; display:flex; gap:10px;}
.status { background: #ccc; display:flex;}
```

```html
<div class="orw">
<span class="link">ss</span>
<div class="orders">sdddds<div class="status">sss</div></div>
<div class="orders">sdddds<div class="status">sss</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot!